# What causes extremely poor XSLT performance: text fragments or priorites?

Tags: performance, xslt, xpath, saxon

I am trying to do some cleanups using XSLT. I want to do some changes on text fragments and leave all the other nodes in peace. However my current implementation runs very slow and consumes a lot of memory. The removal of a small template changes the run time from a minute to a fraction of a second.

This is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:import href="../common/identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" priority="100">
        <xsl:variable name="pass1" select="replace(., '(_|~)', ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pass2" select="replace($pass1, ' , ', ', ')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="final" select="$pass2"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$final"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body/text()[1][. = ' '] | body/text()[last()][. = ' ']"
                  priority="200"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template replaces some characters, the second template removes the first and last text fragments, but only if they contain exactly one space (sadly `normalize-space` does not fit my needs).

This XSLT runs very slow and consumes a lot of memory. If I remove the last templates, the same XSLT runs fast and using a normal amount of memory.

The XSLT is run using Saxon-(HE|EE) 9.5.1.3 inside oXygen 15.2.

**What is causing this big loss of performance?** Is it the use of text fragments in general? The use of priorities? The use of `[1]` and `[last()]`?

Comment: Well which version of which XSLT processor do you use exactly? How do you run it? Have you tried to make use of its profile tools, for instance Saxon 9 has the `-t` option and the `-TP` option http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html. Have you tried a different processor? I don't see why a template that suppresses copying some text nodes would increase the memory usage significantly.

Comment: Performance depends entirely on the XSLT processor you are using, so we need that information. My suspicion would fall on the predicate [last()]. Try [not(following-sibling::text())] to see if that works any better.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I use Saxon 9. I updated the question with the relevant details. I also used the profiling tools before posting this questions but they do not show anything. I will try to format the output of the profiling tools and add it to the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay, using `not(following-sibling::text())` instead of `last()` fixed it. Could you explain why or give some pointers to the problems of `last()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using not(following-sibling::text()) instead of last() fixed it. Could you explain why or give some pointers to the problems of last()?

There are two ways of evaluating patterns: left-to-right, and right-to-left, corresponding to the "formal" and "informal" semantics given in section 5.5.3 of the specification. The right-to-left method is much more efficient, but it cannot be used for all patterns; in particular, patterns that use positional predicates are tricky. Saxon will handle a number of cases efficiently, including `match="para[last()]"`, but for some others, including `match="para[last()-1]"` and (it seems) `match="section/para[last()]"`, it takes the slow-but-methodical route. I'll take a look at the code and see if this can be improved.